# H2O Random Forest Impurity Measure for Classification

Tags: classification, random-forest, decision-tree, h2o

I currently use the DRF implementation of H2O-3 to create a binary classification model. However, I was wondering, that H2O only supports squared error as impurity measure which is usually used to contruct regression trees but no other measure like e.g. Gini which I think are better suited for classification tasks.

Within the documentation I was not able to identify the reasonning for applying this metric also for classification tasks. Can anyone explain to, why this appraoch makes sense?